# "No appropriate constructor available"

Tags: c++

Here is my code, Visual Studio keeps telling me "no appropriate constructor available"

```
    struct Node 
{
    Node(int a, int b, int c);
    int left;
    int right;
    int number;
};
Node::Node(int a, int b, int c)
{
    number = a;
    left = b;
    right = c;
};

int main()
{
    int n, number, left, right;
    cin >> n;
    vector <Node> BST(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> number;
        cin >> left;
        cin >> right;
        Node *leaf = new Node(number, left, right);
        BST.push_back(*leaf);
    }
    vector<Node>::iterator it;
    for (it = BST.begin(); it != BST.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->number<<" "<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

My guess is that I'm missing the default constructor for node but I though that I didn't need it since the compiler would put one for you. Have not idea what's wrong

Comment: The compiler wil not generate a default constructor if you define some other constructor yourself.

Comment: So how would I fix it? just adding a default constructor that does nothing? I tried adding a Node::Node() that does not nothing and didn't fix it

Comment: You don't need the first `n` elements. Replace `vector <Node> BST(n)` with `vector <Node> BST`. The second `n` elements are all you're after.

Comment: Add a default constructor that does something.

Comment: Side note: Each iteration of the loop is leaking a new `Node`. There are better ways to do what's intended. Such as `BST.push_back(Node(number, left, right));` or even usage of `emplace_back`

Comment: It is necessary to both declare the default constructor within the `struct` definition AND to implement it.    Alternatively, make the constructor you have function as needed, but declaring it in the `struct` definition with default values for arguments (aka `Node(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0);`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you want `n` elements in your vector, not `2 * n` elements. Your code currently attempts to pre-fill the vector with `n` elements, which fails because there is no default `Node` value, and *then* you attempt to insert another `n` elements.

If you fix your logic to *not* have any elements in the vector to begin with, then you also don't need a default constructor. Just replace the definition of `BST`:

```
vector<Node> BST;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
  // ...
  BST.push_back(some_value);
}
```

---

There are further problems with your code (including a glaring memory leak). Rather than belabouring them all in detail, here's a revamped version of your program that you can pick apart in your own time:

```
struct Node {
    Node(int a, int b, int c) : left(b), right(c), number(a) {}

    int left;
    int right;
    int number;
};

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n, number, left, right;
    if (!(std::cin >> n)) { std::cerr << "Input error!\n"; std::abort(); }

    std::vector<Node> BST;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!(std::cin >> number >> left >> right)) {
            std::cerr << "Input error!\n"; std::abort();
        }
        BST.emplace_back(number, left, right);
    }

    for (const Node& node : BST) {
        std::cout << node.number << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
Node::Node()
{
  number = 0;
  left = 0;
  right = 0;
};
```

As stated in the comments a default constructor won't be added if you define custom constructors.

Also, as stated below, this

```
Node::Node() : number(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
```

is more efficient and I recommend.

Comment: But why recommend this when the OP's code is obviously misguided on every count, and "making it compile" goes nowhere towards making a meaningful program? The absence of a default constructor actually provided a fantastic diagnostic that the OP's implementation of the algorithm was wrong.

Comment: Better: `Node::Node() : number(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}`

Comment: @KerrekSB He asked a question, I gave him the solution. That's how this website works.

Answer (score 0):

If you define your constructor, you will need to define the default constructor. C++11 onward you can force one using default keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can simply force the compiler to generate the default constructor:

```
struct Node 
{
    Node(int a, int b, int c);
    Node() = default; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    // ...
};
```

As soon you declare your own constructor the compiler won't generate the default constructor.

Comment: Well, yes, you can do that, but does the default constructor so generated build a valid Node?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the default constructor is disabled if you define your own constructor. Hence you cannot call default constructor, if you have your own.

If you need the default constructor too, you have to implement it too.

Do this:

```
Node::Node()
{
  left = //default value
  right = //default value
  number = //default value
}
```

Comment: Why did you feel it necessary to post this, when everything you say has been covered in other answers and comments?

Comment: @NeilButterworth When I was writing this answer there wasn't any. I have a terrible internet connection. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the existing constructor like:

```
Node::Node(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0) : number(a), left(b), right(c)
{

};
```

Using this definition, you are able to create objects in the following manner:

```
Node* n1 = new Node;
Node* n2 = new Node(2, 3, 5);
```